# Exception specifications when deriving from std::exception in C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, exception-specification

I have an exception class as follows:

```
#include <exception>

struct InvalidPathException : public std::exception
{
   explicit InvalidPathException() {}
   const char* what() const;
};

const char*
InvalidPathException::what() const {
    return "Path is not valid";
}
```

When compiling under GCC 4.4 with -Wall -std=c++0x

> error: looser throw specifier for
>   'virtual const char*
>   InvalidPathException::what() const'
>
> error: overriding 'virtual const char*
>   std::exception::what() const throw ()'

Quite right, too, since I'm overriding `std::exception`'s `what()` method that does indeed have a `throw()` exception specifier. But as one will often [be informed](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm), we shouldn't use exception specifiers. And as I understand it, they are [deprecated in C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#cite_ref-sutter0310_6-1), but evidently not yet in GCC with -std=c++0x.

So I'd be interested in the best approach for now. In the code I'm developing I do care about performance and so worry about the oft-mentioned overhead of `throw()`, but in reality is this overhead so severe? Am I right in thinking that I'd only suffer it when `what()` is actually called, which would only be after such an exception is thrown (and likewise for the other methods inherited from std::exception that all have `throw()` specifiers)?

Alternatively, is there a way to work around this error given by GCC?

Comment: If you're only using exceptions for exceptional conditions, not for general program flow, then you shouldn't have to worry about the performance overhead of throwing (or the exception specifier). I've noticed the same thing you are and I simply added the specifiers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Empty `throw` specifications are useful, as they actually enable compiler optimizations at the caller's site, as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions) knows (I don't have a technical quote handy).

And for reasons of optimization opportunities, nothrow-specifications are *not* deprecated in the upcoming standard, they just don't look like `throw ()` any more but are called `noexcept`. Well, yes, and they work slightly differently.

[Here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=481&rll=1)'s a discussion of `noexcept` that also details why traditional nothrow-specifications prohobit optimizations at the callee's site.

Generally, you pay for every `throw` specification you have, at least with a fully compliant compiler, which GCC has, in this respect, appearantly not always been. Those `throw` specifications have to be checked at run-time, even empty ones. That is because if an exception is raised that does not conform to the `throw` specification, stack unwinding has to take place within that stack frame (so you need code for that in addition to the conformance check) and then `std::unexpected` has to be called. On the other hand, you potentially save time/space for every *empty* `throw` specification as the compiler may make more assumptions when calling that function. I chicken out by saying only a profiler can give you the definitive answer of whether your particular code suffers from or improves by (*empty*!) `throws` specification.

As a workaround to your actual problem, may the following work?

- Introduce `#define NOTHROW throw ()` and use it for your exception's `what` and other stuff.
- When GCC implements `noexcept`, redefine `NOTHROW`.

#### Update

As @James McNellis notes, `throw ()` will be forward-compatible. In that case, I suggest just using `throw ()` where you have to and, apart from that, if in doubt, profile.

Comment: Given that `throw()` and `noexcept` and `noexcept(true)` are all equivalent, there should be no need for a `NOTHROW` macro; just use `throw()`.  This works with all current compilers and is forward-compatible once compilers support C++0x `noexcept`.

Comment: With the update I reckon that's a pretty complete answer. Many thanks. The only thing that might be good to add is a mention of where the overhead in incurred.