# Override bad_alloc Exception

Tags: exception

I am trying to change the message for `bad_alloc`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::logic_error;
using std::bad_alloc;


class OutOfRange : public logic_error {
   public:
      OutOfRange(): logic_error("Bad pointer") {}
};


class OutOfMem : public bad_alloc {
   public:
      OutOfMem(): bad_alloc("not enough memory") {}
};
```

`OutOfRange()` works fine, but `OutOfMem` sends me an error:

> No matching function for call to `std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc(const char[21])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile error is telling you that that `bad_alloc` constructor does not take a char *.
e.g. [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)

Instead, note that exception `what` method is vritual and use that instead.

```
   class OutOfMem : public bad_alloc {
      public:
         OutOfMem() {}
         const char *what() const {
             return "not enough memory";
         }
   };
```

Edit: note you might have to state it doesn't throw as follows:

```
 //... as before
 virtual const char * what() const throw () {
     return "not enough memory";
 }
 // as before ...
```

Comment: I try that, it send me an error    looser throw specifier for `virtual const char* OutOfMem::what() const'

Comment: How is `what` defined in std::exception in your setup? Does it have a throw specifier?

Comment: well i only have this on my header 
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <stdexcept>

   using std::logic_error;
   using std::bad_alloc;

Comment: The solution will depend on what version (of gcc I presume) you are using see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282578/exception-specifications-when-deriving-from-stdexception-in-c11

Comment: Or indeed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635464/what-the-c-standard-says-about-loosing-throw-specifier-in-default-destructor